# How to generate data in specific format with AutoFixture?

Tags: c#, autofixture

I have a model class User which is as below:

```
public class User
{
    public string UserName{ get; set; }
    public string Language { get; set; }
    public string Email{ get; set; }
}
```

I am using XUnit and Autofixture for my unit tests. I have a test method which is as below:

```
    [Theory, AutoData]
    public async Task ShouldCreateUser(User user)
    {
      ...
    }
```

The problem is that Autofixture creates random string data for all properties of User class. Is there a way to make Autofixture return specific data format as below:

```
Language --> random data such as "EN", "ES"
Email --> random email address: example@mail.com
```

Answer (score 1):

#### Emails

AutoFixture is able to generate email addresses OOTB using `System.Net.Mail.MailAddress` type. So, you may either change your property type from `string` to `MailAddress` or set it in tests manually.

```
[Theory, AutoData]
public void MailAddressTest(MailAddress email)
{
    // Output: email = "7495f4c5-9f5c-4854-9cbd-e9d3bc53dfcd" <7495f4c5-9f5c-4854-9cbd-e9d3bc53dfcd@example.net>
    Console.Out.WriteLine("email = {0}", email);

    // Output: email = 48f2028f-f055-4745-bf1c-f710e141332a@example.com
    Console.Out.WriteLine("email = {0}", email.Address);
}
```

#### Languages

You can try to get language code from `CultureInfo`. Unfortunately, by default AF [always generate InvariantCulture](https://github.com/AutoFixture/AutoFixture/blob/c56d708b1ef3d03be313848c11d5a52855b54e09/Src/AutoFixture/InvariantCultureGenerator.cs). If you need more languages you have to extend AF. It can be done via a new specimen builder which should pick a random culture from, let's say, all the available cultures (or any other subset of cultures according to your needs):

```
public class RandomCultureGenerator : ISpecimenBuilder
{
    private readonly ExactTypeSpecification _cultureTypeSpecification;
    private readonly CultureInfo[] _cultures;
    private readonly Random _random;

    public RandomCultureGenerator()
    {
        _cultureTypeSpecification = new ExactTypeSpecification(typeof(CultureInfo));
        _cultures = CultureInfo.GetCultures(CultureTypes.NeutralCultures);
        _random = new Random();
    }

    public object Create(object request, ISpecimenContext context)
    {
        if (request == null)
            return new NoSpecimen();

        if (!this._cultureTypeSpecification.IsSatisfiedBy(request))
            return new NoSpecimen();

        var index = _random.Next(_cultures.Length - 1);
        return _cultures[index];
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
[Fact]
public void GenerateRandomCulture()
{
    var fixture = new Fixture();
    fixture.Customize<CultureInfo>(c => new RandomCultureGenerator());
    var culture = fixture.Create<CultureInfo>();
    Console.Out.WriteLine("culture = {0}", culture.TwoLetterISOLanguageName);
}
```